# SQL select on a many-to-many table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got 3 tables: `Movies`, `Actors`, and `MovieActors`. `MovieActors` is a many-to-many relationship of `Movies` and `Actors` with columns `MovieActorId`, `MovieId`, and `ActorId`

How do I find movies that have a certain set of actors in it? For example I want to find all movies that have both Michael Fassbender (actor Id 1) and Brad Pitt (actor Id 2) in them. What would the query look like?

Comment: Jay, I would probably not have a MovieActorID column in the 3rd table. With the current design the same Actor could be assigned to the same movie multiple times. Just have a 2-column table MovieID/ActorID

Comment: It's actually a simplification of the actual table we have, where actors could have multiple roles. Think Tyler Perry movies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it simple, you can just do two `in` clauses:

```
select * from Movies m
where m.MovieId in (select MovieId from MovieActors where ActorId = 1)
and m.MovieId in (select MovieId from MovieActors where ActorId = 2)
```

Performance may not be as good as a single `join`, but it's clean and easy to read.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to join the tables. Filter for the actors and then insure the count has the number of actors you want in it (2 in this case)

```
SELECT 
   m.MovieID
FROM
    Movies m
    INNER JOIN MovieActors ma
    ON m.MovieID = ma.MovieID

WHERE
    ma.ActorID IN (1,2)
GROUP BY 
   m.MovieID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ma.ActorID) = 2
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8e92/2)

**Note**

Thanks to user814064 for pointing out that since Actors can have more than one role on a movie we need to count the `DISTINCT ma.ActorID` not just `*`  The SQL Fiddle Demo demonstrates the difference

Comment: Would you explain `having count = 2`?

Comment: Just ran that on my server and it's giving me movies that do not have the second actor in them.

Comment: @JaySun Can you provide sample data, or even better a SQL Fiddle that shows that?

Comment: I think you misread my question. I'm looking for a movie that have two specific actors in them, regardless of who else is in the movie. See the answer I marked as correct.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. If you look at the original posters recent comment under the question you can see the issue. He has multiple copies of the same actor assigned to a movie.

Comment: @user814064 doh! nice catch then it's `COUNT(DISTINCT ma.actorID)` like in Juergen_d's

Answer (score 2):

```
select m.movieid
from movies m
inner join movieactors ma on ma.movieid = m.movieid
where ma.actorid in (1,2)
group by m.movieid
having count(distinct ma.actorid) = 2
```