# Select rows where join table has same value

Tags: mysql, join

```
product_options
ID | Option
1  | One
2  | Two
3  | Three

product_to_options
ID | Product | Option
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 2       | 2
3  | 2       | 3
```

Essentially, I need to get all the rows from product_options, apart from the 
ones that are supplied where the options are on the same products.

**For example:**

Passing the value of 1, would return nothing.

Passing the value of 2, would return the option with ID 3

Passing the value of 3, would return the option with ID 2.

Comment: Who  is `value` in your examples? ID, Product or Option?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the value would be the Option

Comment: Is confusion because you have two `Option` one integer and one string. You should rename the second one to `Option_ID`

Comment: `Option` refers to the one in `product_to_options`

Comment: Your question isnt clear, sorry.

Comment: How is it not clear? If I pass in `1` it would check the `product_to_options` table for options that are on the same products as `1`, and then return the `product_options` rows with the same IDs.

Comment: isnt clear because variable name are confusing, so not sure what is the variable you are passing, also you dont say what is the `same value` is refer to.

Comment: I am passing `product_to_options.Option` and the same value is `product_to_options.Product`

Comment: So if you pass `product_to_options.Option = 1` why you get nothing ? because `product_to_options.Product` is also `1` Also isnt clear what would you return ?

Comment: I get nothing because I want to return all the other values, apart from the one passed in. I explained that in my question.

Comment: So what you need in return? what you need `product_options` ?

Comment: Yes it would return the rows in the `product_options` table.

Answer (score 1):

I did my best with what I understand.

- `pto.Product = @option` so you get all the rows match `@option`
- `pto.Option <> @option` but filter those with the same ID

.

```
SELECT po.*
FROM product_options po
JOIN (
      SELECT pto.Option
      FROM product_to_options pto
      WHERE pto.Product = @option
        AND pto.Option <> @option
     ) as filter
  ON PO.ID = filter.Option
```

Comment: Not sure why you went with a inline view here but at least it correctly filters out options with the same id

Comment: @ConradFrix Not sure what you mean, but if you see a better way to write it feel free to edit it as a second way.

Answer (score 0):

You can join a table to itself, filter the left table on the value and return the value from the right table.

```
SELECT
     pto2.Option
FROM
   product_to_options pto1
   INNER JOIN    product_to_options pto2
   ON pto1.Product = pto2.Product
   AND pto1.ID <> pto2.ID 
WHERE  
    pto1.option = @option;
```

You should note that you can get more than one value back depending on the data.

[Here's a working sample with minor syntax changes for sql server](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/642761/example-for-42861277?opt.textResults=true) (you'll need to check text-only-results or click through the grid)

Comment: What should I do if I want to get the options that option `1` and option `2` are on?

Comment: @RyanHipkiss That's a different question. Typically you use an IN and a count. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18860401/119477